# Open source text mining visualization software

Tags: open-source, data-visualization

Are there any open source text mining visualization software having similarities to Infranodus (infranodus.com)?

Comment: What features are you looking for in such a program?

Comment: As large a subset as possible of the core features of Infranodus (see website).

Comment: But what are those things you're expecting? Can you list them? What are more important to you? Just following some link doesn't creates a good question. Also, what OS, licence, hardware requirements are you willing to accept? See [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/6957).